# No route matches [GET] "/images/rails.png"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm getting the error:

> No route matches [GET] "/images/rails.png"

I have in my `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Why am I getting this error? It happens on localhost and on Heroku.

Comment: Does the file actually exist?

Comment: @user1028100 well does it?. Perhaps you can share how you are accessing the image in your template or stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is a read-only filesystem. You will need to set your application.rb to look like this:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
config.assets.compile = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
```